# How to store data from html form in variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Basically there is a Google-like search bar, once the user hits submit I need to store it in a variable. There is more to the jQuery than below, but all it is is `document.ready`. The reason I need the data in a variable is because after that, I will use `$.post` and send it to my API.

```
("#form").submit( function(res) {
    var id = $(this).JSON.parse(data);

//Other attempted ways of getting input. 
    // $(this).data
    // $(this).data('button')
    // document.getElementById('id').value
    // $(this).getElementById('id').value
    // $(this).JSON.parse(data) -> "cannot parse undenfined, means no JSON data."


$.post('/search', {id: id }, function(data) { 
        data = JSON.parse(data);
        $("#count").text("we analyzed...");
        $("#result1".text(data));
        $("#totals").text("with a score of..");
        $("#result2").text(data);
    });
    res.redirect('/test/' + id);
});
```

```html
<form id="form">
    <div class="featurette">
        <div class="featurette-inner text-center">
            <div class="search">
                <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit">Search</button>
                    </span>
                    <input type="text" name="id" input id="searchbar" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your search term....">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</form>
```

Comment: var formData = $("form").serialize() should do the trick

Comment: The HTML seems invalid? Also, does the form submit, and the page reload?

Comment: @adeneo I am using node.js and handlebars. How else does it seem invalid?

Comment: @WillAshley because you're missing a closing `</div>` tag and the `input` has an incorrect `input` attribute

Comment: @mhodges it returns undefined. I've added the rest of the jquery if it helps. I also get an error saying redirect is not a function.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan when I added a closing div tag it didnt change the input storing issue, but when the page reloads like it normally does, the GET request for my stylesheets was denied leaving the page looking very...bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, note that your `#form` selector is missing the `$`.

Assuming that you mean that you want to retrieve the value the user typed in the `#searchbar` input field, you can just use `$('#searchbar').val()`:

```
$("#form").submit( function(res) {
    var search = $('#searchbar').val();
    // use the 'search' variable as needed here...
    // $.post('url...', { searchTerm: search });
});
```

Also note that your HTML is invalid. You're missing a closing `</div>` and there is no `input` attribute on an `input` element. Try this:

```
<form id="form">
    <div class="featurette">
        <div class="featurette-inner text-center">
            <div class="search">
                <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit">Search</button>
                    </span>
                    <input type="text" name="id" id="searchbar" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your search term...." />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you sir. The term is stored. Do you know why it is saying 'error; redirect is not a function'?

Comment: It's because the `event` object that's passed in to the function (which you're storing in `res`) has no `redirect` method. If you want to do a redirect, use `window.location.assign('url...');`. However your AJAX call is rather redundant if you're redirecting the page immediately after it anyway.